# Do I play C and G as natural in G major?

Tags: key, key-signatures

For any major played, (G major, D major, etc.) do we play everything else as a *natural*? (Ex. G major only uses every `F` as an `F#`, so would `C` and `G` both be played as a *natural* in the piece if they are there?)

Comment: I answered your similar question yesterday. The G major scale is G A B C D E F♯ G. D major is D E F♯ G A B C♯ D. Each major scale differs from every other major scale by at least one sharp or flat. Look up the circle of fifths. This shows you that keys and scales add a sharp (or lose a flat) as you move clockwise. (C has no sharps or flats. G has 1. D, 2. A, 3. E, 4. B, 5. F♯, 6.) You add a flat or lose a sharp as you move counter-clockwise. (C, 0. F, 1. B♭, 2. E♭, 3. A♭, 4. D♭, 5. G♭, 6.)

Answer (score 3):

If you are in the key of G Major you only have one accidental: F# as you already know. You will see the # noted in the key so every F you find will be sharp if not differently stated. And again, **if not differently stated**, this means every other note will be natural.

But remember, a scale is only a reference, not a strict unbreakable rule. You can find other accidentals even without modulating to a different key. Those are used for a lot of reasons: building tension, supporting the harmony, bridging between two chords and so on..

So in the same piece, in the same G Major scale, the C (or even the G as every other note) can be used natural, sharp or flat.

Answer (score 1):

I THINK I understand your question!

Yes, when playing a scale the key signature tells you which notes are to be played as sharps (or flats).  The remaining notes are played natural.

Answer (score 1):

Well, yes. If the key signature says 3 flats, everything else is natural. If they were anything else, we'd have to write it in the key signature!